# Express req.query.time return NaN

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm having a very strange issue whereby getting the time value from my HTTP POST req in express always result in NaN if I'm trying to convert it to ISO String or even Date object.

Here is my URL request:
http://localhost:3000/sensor/reading/update?value=33.5&time=1430217238000

update.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var moment = require('moment');

router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
var time = moment(req.query.time);
}
```

I am sure that the req.query.time is valid since I can see the exact value in console.log(req.query.time). Even var time = new Date(req.query.time) also result in invalid date.

Totally lost of thoughts here :(

Comment: That's a POST route, you're sure it's GET data you're trying to get ?

Comment: Also note that `new Date("1430217238000")` is in fact not a valid date

Comment: Indeed this is a HTTP POST to get the time and sensor readings from my sensors and then relay it to another service API like graphing and database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting a string, and you probably want an integer

```
var time = new Date( parseInt( req.query.time, 10) );
```

Comment: Thanks I must have overlooked it. I'm so used to parsing JSON that automatically treat numbers as numbers.